# Can't use gvim with pathogen under windows

Tags: windows, vim

I have pathogen setup and working fine under Linux, but when I try to use the some configuration with gvim73 under windows it doesn't work at all.  I don't get any errors but it does nothing.

Here is my dotfiles repository up on git.  I've checked this out to ~/vimfiles and I added the following to _vimrc:

```
filetype off
call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
```

I've tried just about everything including putting the autoload/pathogen.vim and bundles/ folders in the /vim73 directory under program files.  Nothing.

Does anyone have some experience with this? I'm assuming there is something windows specific that needs to happen to make this work.

Edit: It is probably also worth noting I can run `pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()` even using tab completion so pathogen is being loaded, but my plugins are just not working.

Comment: Are you putting bundles folder in your vim runtimepath?  Check by issuing Vim command, `:echo &rtp`

Comment: When I run that I see each bundle folder listed, (e.g., C:\Users\chris.nicola\vimfiles\bundles\blogit) but the actual plugins just aren't working.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  Sadly it seems this may have just been an issue with me forgetting to init my submodules for packages among a couple other random issues.  I did end up installing the x64 version of Vim72 as well, but I doubt that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some kind of issue on Windows when I used the pathogen version provided by Vim.org

However, using [github pathogen head](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), the issue was fixed.

I think the latest release from Vim.org is from January last year, and the latest commit on github is from November.

Specifically, I had this issue with after directory:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/closed#issue/12

Comment: No luck, I was already using the latest github version.  Can I see your _vimrc file perhaps? And where do you have your /autoload and /bundle folders?  Are they under ~/vimfiles?

Comment: @Chris Nicola : My vimrc + associated fodlers are there : https://github.com/XavierT/Vimrc and I have put everything in ~/vimfiles

Comment: @XavierT. Unrelated to this post, but did you implement a custom vimscript function to display the [annotations in comments](https://github.com/XavierT/Vimrc/blob/master/vimrc#L79) for your `set statusline=%f%m%r%h\ [%L]\ [%{&ff}]\ %y%=[%p%%]\ [line:%05l,col:%03v]` line?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure it will help but here is my working configuration:

- d:\soft\vim\vim73\ - gvim itself, i.e.
  pathogen.vim is copied into the
  d:\soft\vim\vim73\autoload\
- d:\soft\vim\vimfiles\bundle - directory
  for plugins

Corresponding lines from configuration file d:\soft\vim\_vimrc:

```
" Use pathogen to load plugins from bundle directory
filetype off
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

Also I changed pathogen#helptags because original didn't work for my paths:

```
dir[0 : strlen($VIM)-1] !=# $VIM has been changed to stridx(dir, "bundle") != -1
```

Answer (score 5):

It's an old question, but I had the same issue and solution as the OP, and it has a mildly annoying origin. I was using the following script to install everything on Windows (Vista+ and run as admin if you want the `mklink` part to work):

```
cd "%UserProfile%"
rmdir vimfiles /S /Q
git clone http://github.com/brymck/dotvim.git vimfiles
del _vimrc
mklink _vimrc vimfiles\vimrc
cd vimfiles
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

The above is just a Windows-y version of a [Vimcast on syncing your Vim preferences with GitHub](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/) and is fairly straightforward, so I figure others may be doing something similar.

Anyway, your experience may differ (and this doesn't apply to Cygwin), but when I just copied and pasted this into the terminal, `git submodule update` got "eaten" while `git submodule init` was running. I didn't figure it out initially because this had never happened to me on Linux. In short, wait until everything else has completed before running `git submodule update` and you should be golden. (Also, FWIW, I'm using the [current version of pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/tree/master/autoload), which was last updated September 25, 2011.)

Answer (score 3):

For me renaming the .vim folder into vimfiles solved the problem for Vim 7.4.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a long time ago, but maybe it will help someone ... I had the same issue.  It wouldn't give me any errors, but no plugins would be loaded.  I then RTFM and noticed that he explicitly states at the top of [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) page that it should go in your **vimrc** not **gvimrc**.  After I changed that I had no problems.